# Why i am not get exact passing text using $_GET when that text contains #?

Tags: php

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
echo $_GET['id']; }
<a href="test.php?id=10#12">Click Here</a>
```

Output: 10
Why i am not get `10#12.`

Comment: Because the "#" is a special character in an URL indicating a hash. Use urlencode() for the value of "id".

Comment: encode your **id** from client side and send it to your this funtion

Comment: Is it possible to read hash?

Comment: @Typoheads is right, you should (url-)encode the hash character (%23) so the URL would read `test.php?id=10%2312` and try again

Comment: Instead of `10#12`, you can pass `10%2312`

Comment: <?php 
   if(isset($_GET['id']))
   {
 echo $_REQUEST['id'];
   }
?>
<a href="/test_magento_ajax/test2.php?id=<?php echo urlencode('10#12') ?>">Click Here</a>

Comment: Now problem solved thanks